# Ember.js delay in passing object properties to child component after setting them in parent

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm working in Ember 3.1.4.

In keeping with the DDAU pattern, I have a set `setProperty` action in my controller, which simply accepts the property name and the value to set it to, and then does so.

I then pass the action into my component, and I can call it to set a property at the controller level, and then pass the property back down into the component.

When setting a property to a string, it works as expected and if I get the property immediately after calling the `setProperty` action, it returns the new value (As when setting `simpleProp` below).

Strangely, when I use `setProperty` to set a property to an empty object, or to set a child property on an object, the property returns `undefined` if I get it immediately after calling the action, but returns the new value if I use a setTimeout of 1 millisecond.

What causes this, and is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

**Setting a property to an empty object**

Controller

```js
setProperty: function(property, value) {
  this.set(property, value);
},
```

my-component.js

```js
didInsertElement() {
  this.setProperty('parentObject', {});
  console.log(this.get('parentObject')); // undefined
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.get('parentObject')); // {}
  }, 1);
  this.set('simpleProp', 'foo');
  console.log(this.get('simpleProp')); // 'foo'
}
```

Template

```
{{my-component simpleProp=simpleProp parentObject=parentObject setProperty=(action "setProperty")}}
```

**Setting a child property on an existing object**

Controller

```js
init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  this.parentObject = {};
}
setProperty: function(property, value) {
  this.set(property, value);
},
```

my-component.js

```js
didInsertElement() {
  this.setProperty('parentObject.childProp', 'bar');
  console.log(this.get('childProp')); // undefined
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.get('childProp')); // 'bar'
  }, 1);
  this.set('simpleProp', 'foo');
  console.log(this.get('simpleProp')); // 'foo'
}
```

Template

```
{{my-component simpleProp=simpleProp childProp=parentObject.childProp  setProperty=(action "setProperty")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is against Ember's design pattern because Controllers are considered singletons. The [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/controllers/) state that:

> Controllers are singletons so we should avoid keeping state that does
>   not derive from either the Model or Query Parameters since these would
>   persist in between activations such as when a user leaves the Route
>   and then re-enters it.

Because of Ember's bi-directional data flow, you should simply be able to `this.set()` in the component and completely get rid of `this.setProperty()` in the controller.